# dotNet watcher with -- project parameter and running an application stopped working in .NET 8

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0, hot-reload, file-watcher, .net-8.0

In .NET 6, it is possible to use the `dotnet cli` this way:

```
dotnet watch --project DotNetWatch.msbuild MyWebApplication.dll
```

where `DotNetWatch.msbuild` contains an `ItemGroup` with the Watch files, for example:

```
<Project>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Watch Include="*.json" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The same command doesn't work in .NET 8 because it attempts to execute `DotNetWatch.msbuild` instead of `MyWebApplication.dll`.

This is the output in .NET 8:

```
dotnet watch  Started
Unable to run your project.
Ensure you have a runnable project type and ensure 'dotnet run' supports this project.
A runnable project should target a runnable TFM (for instance, net5.0) and have OutputType 'Exe'.
The current OutputType is 'Library'.
dotnet watch ❌ Exited with error code 1
```

Is there any chance this issue will be fixed? I'm aware that I can modify the command to use 'dotnet watch run --project MyWebApplication.csproj' and include the Watch itemGroup in MyWebApplication.csproj, but I'd like to confirm if this is a known compatibility issue before making the change.

I tested with 8.0.100-preview.5.23303.2 and 8.0.100-preview.3.23178.7. The same thing happens with both.

Comment: Could you please tell me what's your .net core 8 version?